# Master.js won't load in Firefox

Tags: support, javascript, browser-cache

The [current version of SO's Master.js](http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=6180) (6180) won't load in Firefox 3.6 `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 GTB6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)`.
Therefore, vote counts don't work.

It works fine in Chrome and Fiddler.

### Content Encoding Error

---

> The page you are trying to view cannot
>   be shown because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression.

---

- Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed that browser updates have been causing caching problems with SO's javascript.  I had a similar issue a couple times when I updated chrome, and I've seen other stories like this.  The solution is generally "clear your cache", and beyond that the problem usually fixes itself after the first time you run into it.  It really is generally just a caching issue.

That said, I don't see the same problem on other sites and so there may be a genuine bug here somewhere.  It could be there's something in how SO has their caching setup that's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I pressed Ctrl + F5 and the problem was fixed.

I wonder how it happened... (Was the cache corrupted?)